# Launch shell scripts via keyboard shortcut in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

The only workaround I am aware of is using applescript in Spark/FastScripts with

```
do shell script "python script.py"
```

Comment: FastScripts can launch non-AppleScript (e.g. Python) scripts directly. Just put the script (or an alias to it; symlinks do not seem to work) somewhere in ~/Library/Scripts.

Answer (score 4):

In 10.6 Snow Leopard it's quite easy to add *any* command to the Services menu of each application (or specific applications), and then assign a keyboard shortcut.

Here on Super User, see [Fast User Switching/Apple Menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu/46308#46308) for an example that invokes some shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to launch an application or script from the keyboard. There is also [IronAHK](http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/) (AutoHotkey rewrite) which works under Mono, example:

```
^n::Run, /path/to/script.py
```

although make sure the script has sufficient execute permissions and a shebang line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use automator to make a contextual menu invoked script.

Answer (score 0):

Other applications that launch AppleScripts like FastScripts (lite) include Quicksilver, Butler, and ControllerMate.

I believe Quicksilver may allow for the execution of Shell scripts directly from within the application, but I dislike Quicksilver on the point that it seems to flake out more often than Butler does.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't see anything wrong with your workaround. It seems like a perfect solution, so much so that when I found this question in a Google search, that's the one I used. Thanks! :-)