# What is the sleep and lock keyboard shortcut for MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite

**Sleep** and **Lock** are 2 different things. How to do it in mac. It always goes to sleep.

Like if I have set a file on download and I want it to lock it but it goes to sleep.

Please let me know how to do it.

My research by now is given below:

**given below option is good when you only want to lock your system but what when you want your system to hybernate**

> In System Preferences > Energy Saver, set "Computer Sleep" to "Never"
>   In System Preferences > Security & Privacy, check the box for "Require
>   password [immediately] after sleep or screen saver begins"

Comment: Confusing question... if it sleeps or hibernates, the download will stop. Set the computer to never sleep, then use Mission Control - Hot Corners to start the screensaver.

Comment: there are 2 things that I want to do as we do in windows Sleep and Lock
Either i am able to make it sleep or lock. Is there a way to do both thingsn depending on the situation? @Tetsujin

Comment: You can't sleep it if you want it to continue downloading, you lock it by enabling the screensaver

Comment: See also [Create a keyboard shortcut for fast user switching in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/44433/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-fast-user-switching-in-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard shortcut for

**Lock** : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> (If your mac has an optical drive)

           <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> (for the newer mac that doesn't have an optical drive)

**Sleep**: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> (If your mac has an optical drive )

           <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> (for the newer mac that doesn't have an optical drive)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Power puts the screen to sleep, which is not the same as locking (so, this is not the same as Keychain's "Lock Screen" option). To be prompted for a password when returning to the machine, one also needs to enable Security, General, Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins.

Answer (score 0):

On keyboard, to put MacBook to sleep, I use

```
Shift + Control + FN + F8
```